# Cannot update .Text property of asp:TextBox inside asp:UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have several dropdownlists and textboxes inside an `<asp:UpdatePanel>`, which should let me edit some details after selecting an item inside an `<asp:GridView>`. The grid is not inside the updatepanel.

From the UpdatePanels' .Load() method, I change the .Text of a few `<asp:Label>`, `<asp:TextBox>`, and I set the .SelectedValue of some `<asp:DropDownList>`.

All labels are updated correcly, but the new .Text of the `<asp:TextBox>` and .SelectedValue of `<asp:DropDownList>` are not visible in the HTML output. After setting the new value, I can see that it has been set with *QuickWatch* from Visual Studio.

What is causing this, and how can I solve my problem?

I am using Visual Studio 2008 with .Net 3.5

Comment: Where (in which event) exactly are you updating text-box/drop-down?

Comment: My guess is you are probably setting controls early in page life cycle and values are getting overridden from request. Try setting values in Page_Load event.

Comment: I update the textboxes and dropdowns from panelDetails_Load(), which is referenced from <asp:UpdatePanel ID="panelDetails" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server" onload="panelDetails_Load">

Comment: I tried setting the values in Page_Load, but it seems they are still overwritten by request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude, just set the .Text in your UpdatePanels PreRender() method. It will solve your problems.

...... Thanks for all the help, guys. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is when you select an item in the `<asp:GridView>` nothing is being posted back to the server?  Is autopostback on?

In addition you need to set the update panel trigger to postback (and hence get the new value) whenever a selection is made in `<asp:GridView>`.

Please comment if I've got the wrong end of the stick.

Comment: Hi, I understand how you might think this. I post back to the server using __doPostBack from my own javascript. If the Load method was not run, the <asp:Label>s would not have been updated either, would they?

Comment: Are you saying the Load method is occuring AFTER you've clicked the GridView?

Comment: When I click the GridView, the UpdatePanel is updated, and the code function panelDetails_Load in Default.aspx.cs is run. My UpdatePanel refers to panelDetails_Load.